# What does 扔下 mean in 还有的人把车扔下不管?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the following sentence:

> 据一位遭遇拥堵的人介绍说，隧道里一小时只能行进几百米，也去不了厕所，有的人下车走向紧急出口，还有的人把车**扔下**不管。

扔 means "throw" or "hurl", but "throwing a car away" doesn't make sense. From the context, I feel it means people get out of the car and push it from the back of the car.

My questions:

- Is this assumption correct?
- If that is true, why doesn't an author write a clearer way, such as:

> 还有的人把车推下不管。

Comment: is a standing expression 扔下不管：bkrs: abandon, [例句] 这工作我不能扔下不管, 同义: 抛到九霄云外, 撇在脑后 iciba: Drop it.我们听说有女人离家出走，扔下了家人不管。& more

Comment: 这里“扔下”有点“留下”的意思

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not. "扔" here means something like "discard" or "abandon". They are now suffering from a (terrible) traffic jam, not a faulty engine, so they don't need to push the car anyway.

It means that the people got so impatient that that left the car where they were and walked away.

Comment: Thanks and that makes sense! The meaning isn't listed on Pleco but I found it is on bkrs - https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=扔

Comment: But then it is ridiculous to discard the car. It is expensive and not something I want to discard, even in such a situation... But there are always crazy people...

Comment: You are welcome. I am happy to answer other questions if I can. Also note user6065's comment. I agree that's ridiculous so only a few are doing that and maybe they'll decide to come back to pick up the car later anyway ...

Answer (score 0):

“Throw” and “abandon” are both correct.

“Throw” has the meaning of “send suddenly into a particular state or condition” in the Oxford Dictionary of English.

And the same is 扔.